# Unable to start listener of standby database

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, dataguard, standby

As part of data guard configuration, I've installed standby database using Oracle Software only and configured .ora files/folders as required. But while trying to start the listener or check the status in standby, it's throwing the following error.

```
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00511: No listener
64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

Then, I tried to start db using pfile and that too shows error as follows.

```
SQL> startup pfile=C:\app_home\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\database\initLOCAL2.ora
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

As I'm doing this for the first time, I'm very much confused at this stage. How can I resolve this?

Comment: "Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))" ... hostname missing? A cursory check shows error 61 relates to diskfull ,so check that is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I follow when creating a standby for a dataguard environment on windows server, please confirm in comments at which step you currently are to help identify your issue here.
(prd1 is the current alive instance, stby1 is the standby instance you're trying to create)

1- install the oracle binaries and patch them to the same level as the live instance without create a database on the stby1's host server

2- On the prd1 instance create a control file for the standby `ALTER DATABASE CREATE STANDBY CONTROLFILE AS  'D:\CONTROL01.CTL';`

3- copy the content of %ORACLE_HOME%\database (windows) to the same path from prd1 to stby1

4- use a CMD window to manually create the windows services for the standby database instance

```
set ORACLE_HOME=[path to oracle_home]

oradim -new -sid STBY1

set ORACLE_SID=STBY1

sqlplus / as sysdba

startup mount;
```

5- Make sure the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora files are configured correctly on both prd1 and stby1

%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin\tnsnames.ora on both server contains something like

```
prd1_server1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = prd1)
    )
  )
stby1_server2 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server2)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = stby1)
    )
  )
```

6- %ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin\listener.ora on server1 (prd1) contains

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server1)(PORT = 1521))
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME =prd1_DGMGRL)
      (ORACLE_HOME = [path to oracle_home])
      (SID_NAME = prd1)
    )
  )
```

7- listener.ora on stby1 server2 contains something like

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server2)(PORT = 1521))
  )


SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
     (GLOBAL_DBNAME =stby1_DGMGRL)
      (ORACLE_HOME = [path to oracle_home])
      (SID_NAME = stby1)
    )
  )
```

8- Once you got all the above settings figured out you go on the stby1 instance and recover the database using SQLPLUS

```
RECOVER STANDBY DATABASE;
```

Comment: I faced the following error while trying to startup mount/nomount as instructed in Step 4.      `SQL> startup nomount;
ORA-16032: parameter LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 destination string cannot be translated
ORA-09291: sksachk: invalid device specified for archive destination
OSD-04018: Unable to access the specified directory or device.
O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.`           I've checked the file location, it does exist there. Then, what could be the reason for this error?